# Convert and convert back datetime in Django

Tags: django, datetime, feedparser

I am parsing feeds using feedparser and I am trying to store updated or updated_parsed attributes of feeds in Django db.

But it shows an error as `[u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']`

Please tell me how to convert updated and updated_parsed such that it can be stored in the Django db such that I can (convert and reuse) or just reuse the date stored in db while parsing in this way:

```
feedparser.parse("url", modified = lastupdate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time, datetime, feedparser, calendar
feed = feedparser.parse('www.popgadget.net')
feed_updated_date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(feed.feed.updated_parsed))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) object?

You will need to use `strptime()` and `strftime()` to convert datetimes.
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thanks @MuhammetCan for ur reply. The methods u suggested convert date from and to string and the dates which feedparser returns are not string. They are in nine tuple format. As of now I am using this feed_updated_date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(feed.feed.updated_parsed))